# How can I disable/stop a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a JavaScript file with jQuery.pep (Drag and Drop jQuery plugin). I'm starting the plugin With this code:

```
Drag.pep();
```

Now, I don't know how to disable/stop it. Here is a code section from the file: `jquery.pep.js`. I think it might help you to answer:

```
$[pluginName] = {
  stopAll: function () {
    disable = true;
    return this;
  },
  startAll: function () {
    disable = false;
    return this;
  }
};
```

The Variable "pluginName" is "pep". Here is the [full jQuery pep code](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js) (github):

Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that should probably do it:

```
$.pep.stopAll(); // stops all peps
```

edit:

in the code there is a function which could be called on an instance object:

```
Pep.prototype.forceStop = function(){
  $(this.el).trigger( this._endTrigger );
};
```

the instance is built here and saved into the data-attribute:

```
// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Pep( this, options ));
        }
    });
};


$('your-selector').data('plugin_pep').forceStop();
```

i tried to do that, it called the forceStop method, but it did not end up doing that. i researched and think what it does is to stop an animation which is currently in progress.

what you could do now is to override the drag-method which could be given with the options when you need it, and immediatly force the stop when the animation is triggered.

i do not like that much, but as i see the code right now, i dont see any chance of doing it another way (docs are missing here ;-()

this should work:

```
var myPep = $('your-selector').data('plugin_pep');
myPep.options.drag = function(ev, obj) {
  obj.forceStop();
};
```

edit2: if you want to make it draggable again, just override the function again with an empty function:

```
myPep.options.drag = function() {};
```

Comment: First, thank you very much!! That's correct, The only thing is, that it doesn't stop only my current object - Drag.pep() - , It stop all of my other objects too - Drag1.pep(), Drag2.pep() ... - any ideas? Sorry if i been misunderstood... Thank you again!!!!

Comment: edited my comment, if you want this to be more clean you probably should have to put some more code into the plugin, which should not be that difficult (add a enabled/disabled boolean to the instances

Comment: WOW!!! Im really appreciate your help! you are the best! Im Testing it right now. . . :)

Comment: Its Work!! So simple.. you are an angel! Thank you!! :D